# uitableviewcell alternating background cell colors even for cells without data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I know how to set alternating colors to a tableviewcell, but how can I set all the visible rows to have an alternating color? For instance, right now if I only have 2 cells with data, only 2 cells will have background colors - how do I fill the backgrounds of the empty cells too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add dummy cells to the end of your list.

Comment: i can do that, but was wondering if there was a more suitable way

Answer (score 2):

try doing some thing like this:
(a)Add only required number of dummy rows
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

```
if ([UIAppDelegate.getwaitlistArray count]>=numberOfVisibleRowsOnYourScreen) {
    return [UIAppDelegate.getwaitlistArray count];
}
else{
    return ([UIAppDelegate.getwaitlistArray count] + numberOfVisibleRowsOnYourScreen - [UIAppDelegate.getwaitlistArray count]);
}
```

}
(b)Alternare your cell:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//alternating cell back ground color
if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:237.0/255.0f green:237.0/255.0f blue:237.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
}else
{

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:247.0/255.0f green:247.0/255.0f blue:247.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
}
```

}

(c)in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
//Create your lables/buttons/text/image
nameLabel.test=@"Whatever";   .....   ......
```

......

```
if (indexPath.row < [YourArray count]) { Populate your data here in the cells } else { cell.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE; nameLabel.text=@""; } return cell; }
```